# How to apply recursion

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

**Problem Statement :**

You are situated in an N dimensional grid at position (x1,x2,...,xN). The dimensions of the grid are (D1,D2,...DN). In one step, you can walk one step ahead or behind in any one of the N dimensions. (So there are always 2×N possible different moves). In how many ways can you take M steps such that you do not leave the grid at any point? You leave the grid if at any point xi, either xi≤0 or xi>Di.

**Input Format**

The first line contains the number of test cases T. T test cases follow. For each test case, the first line contains N and M, the second line contains x1,x2,…,xN and the 3rd line contains D1,D2,…,DN.

**Output Format**

Output T lines, one corresponding to each test case. Since the answer can be really huge, output it modulo 1000000007.

**Constraints**

1≤T≤10

1≤N≤10

1≤M≤300

1≤Di≤100

1≤xi≤Di

**Sample Input**

1

2 3

1 1

2 3

**Sample Output**

12

If this was in **1D** the solution can be like this : solve(i+1)+solve(i-1);

in **2D** : solve(i+1,j)+solve(i-1,j)+solve(i,j+1)+solve(i,j-1); How can i program it for N Dimensions? Is their some general steps for making recursion statements like above which could help in making recursive statements

Most solutions which i saw are in bottom up or top down manner i am not able to understand them ? is their any way to understand them ,as i have always practiced dp using recursion + memoization i find it hard to understand them

how to do memoization ? which data structure to use?,  where to use modulo 1e 7( in the final answer only)??

**UPDATE**
**THANKS TO BARNEY FOR SOLUTION** but getting **TLE** for most cases how to do it faster
code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Grid_Walking {
    private static String[] n;
    private static int moves;

    private static HashMap<String, Integer> hm;
    private static BufferedReader br;

    private static String[] s;

    private static int dimen;
    private static int[] present;
    private static int[] dimlen;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while (t > 0) {
            n = br.readLine().split(" ");
            dimen = Integer.parseInt(n[0]);
            present = new int[dimen];
            dimlen = new int[dimen];
            moves = Integer.parseInt(n[1]);

            s = br.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < dimen; i++) {
                present[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]) - 1;
            }
            s = br.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < dimen; i++) {
                dimlen[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
            }
            hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            System.out.println(solve(present, moves) % 1000000007);
            t--;
        }

    }

    private static int solve(int[] x, int moves) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int result = 0;
        String s = Arrays.toString(x) + moves;
        if (hm.containsKey(s)) {
            return hm.get(s);
        }
        if (moves == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dimen; i++) {
            // System.out.println("fjfvnfjbv");
            if (x[i] > 0) {
                x[i] = x[i] - 1;
                result = result + solve(x, moves - 1);
                x[i] = x[i] + 1;
            }
            if (x[i] < dimlen[i] - 1) {
                x[i] = x[i] + 1;
                result = result + solve(x, moves - 1);
                x[i] = x[i] - 1;
            }
        }
        hm.put(s, result % 1000000007);
        return result % 1000000007;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Barney recursion worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key to this is that from any position, each dimension may have 0, 1 or 2 possible moves:

- 2 moves if you are in the middle of that dimension
- 1 move if you are at one of the edges
- 0 moves if the dimension only has size 1 (i.e. you are on both edges)

For example, in two dimensions you have something like:

```
+---+---+---+---+
+ a +   +   +   +
+---+---+---+---+
+   +   + c +   +
+---+---+---+---+
+   + b +   +   +
+---+---+---+---+
```

- from a you can move one place in both dimensions
- from b you can move one place in the vertical dimension and two places in the horizontal
- from c you can move two places in both dimensions

So the total number of moves you can make is the number of moves from the current location, plus the total from each new location. This second part is the recursion.

So something like the following pseudo code:

```
N is number of dimensions
D is array 1 to N of dimensions
X is array 1 to N of current position

int solve(array D, array X, int moves) {

    // base case when no more moves possible
    if (moves == 0)
        return 1

    // memo key is current position plus number of moves - this code is
    // java and creates a string similar to "[2, 3]4"
    String memoKey = Arrays.toString(X) + String.valueOf(moves);
    if (hashMap.containsKey(memoKey)) {
      return hashMap.get(memoKey);
    }

    // accumulate results from all possible moves in all dimensions
    int result = 0

    // check each dimension
    for n = 1 to N {

        // if we are not at the start of this dimension
        // then add all moves for a decrease of one place
        if (X[n] > 1) {
            X[n] = X[n] - 1
            result = result + solve(D, X, moves - 1)
            X[n] = X[n] + 1
        }

        // if we are not at the end of this dimension
        // then add all moves for a increase of one place
        if (X[n] < D[n]) {
            X[n] = X[n] + 1
            result = result + solve(D, X, moves - 1)
            X[n] = X[n] - 1
        }
    }

    // memoise result for later
    hashMap.put(memoKey, result);

    return result
}
```

**Update**

Included memoisation - may not be the most efficient but it explains one fairly straightforward approach.

Comment: what is the secong if for ?, will it not double the answers?

Comment: @sesy The first `if` checks if a decrease in the current dimension is possible - i.e. we are not a the start of that dimension. If so, then it moves 'down' one place in that  dimension and recurses. The second `if` does the same but for moving 'up' in that dimension. Either test may succeed or fail depending on the position and the dimension size, so you get the 0, 1 or 2 possible moves mentioned in the answer. That help?

Comment: thanks !! recursion worked , i have tried to apply memoization ,but it doesn't seem to work, works only for small inputs i don't no why , getting TLE for majority cases , can you check it please and suggest some better way for memoization?

Comment: @Berney removed the solution as it was containing too much error s can you suggest better ways of memoization

Comment: @sesy sure - the key I would use for memo is the current location plus the number of moves (from [1,1] with one move left is a different value to [1,1] with two moves left). I've updated the example code to include a Java implementation.

Comment: @Barney , the solution you posted is called backtracking , which is one of the variant of recursion.

Answer (score 7):

This problem may be solved efficiently in the following way using a two level DP approach:

First, solve the problem for each dimension separately. This means that for each dimension, compute the number of ways to make 0, 1, ..., M steps in that dimension only (starting from the given starting position). You can solve this similar to the way you described it in your proposed DP Java code. You can store the solution for example in an integer matrix where the number of rows corresponds to the number of dimensions and the number of columns is M+1. Note that for each dimension, you must compute not only how many ways exist to make M steps, but also how many ways exist to make M-1, M-2, ... and 0 steps. We need this information for the second level.

Second, compute the number of ways to make 0, 1, ..., M steps only using the first j dimensions. Assume that you have already computed the number of ways how to make 0, 1, ..., M steps only using the first j-1 dimensions. How many ways are there to make i steps by using the first j dimensions?

- You can make 0 steps in dimension j and i steps in dimensions < j,
- or 1 step in dimension j and i-1 steps in dimensions < j,
- ...
- or i-1 steps in dimension j and 1 step in dimensions < j,
- or i steps in dimension j and 0 steps in dimensions < j.

Let's assume you make i-k steps in dimension j and k steps in dimensions < j. The number of ways to make i-k steps in dimension j was already computed in the first level---let's denote this quantity as a. The number of ways to make k steps in dimensions < j is computed recursively---let's denote this quantity as b. The number of ways to make i-k steps in dimension j and k steps in dimensions < j is then given by a * b * (i choose k). DP can be used to make the recursion more efficient by caching computed results (in this case the key consists of two things: the dimension j and the number of steps i).

Note that you have to perform your computations modulo 1000000007. In order to compute the binomial coefficient modulo a prime number, you might find this [link](https://barkingbogart.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/cnk-mod-1000000007/) helpful.

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

N-dimensional array can be flatten into 1 dimensional array index, that the size of the final index is D1*D2*...*DN. formula similar as follows:

```
// this take (x1,x2,...xn) & (D1, D2, ..., DN) to produce single index.
uint64_t flatten(int N, int x[], int D[]) {
  uint64_t index = 0, mult = 1;
  for (int i = N-1; i>0; i--) {
    index += x[i];
    index *= D[i-1];
  }
  index += x[0];
  return index;
}

// this is the reverse
void unflatten(int N, int x[], int D[], uint64_t index) {
  for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
    x[i] = index % D[i];
    index /= D[i];
  }
  x[N-1] = index;
}
```

Use this way to implement your N-dimensional dynamic programming.

Comment: can you explain a little more didn't get it , how to flatten it

Comment: let index to be final flattened index. if there's only 1 dimension, then index = x1. If there're 2 dimensions, let's say D1 = 5, D2 = 6, then (x1,x2) will be mapped to (x2 * 5 + x1). If there're 3 dimensions, then (x1, x2, x3) will be mapped to (x3 * D2 + x2) * D1 + x1. Using this way N-dimensional indexes can be transformed in to 1-dimensional index.

Comment: If N-dimensional indexes can be transfer into 1-dimensional array index, that dynamic programming on that is much easier. The answer given by @Barney is using the recursion method but still it's difficult to transfer it into a dynamic programming manner. Notice that dynamic programming has a complexity of O(D1*D2*...*DN * N * moves) which is much much faster than recursion algorithm which has a complexity of O((2*N)^moves).

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java solution that computes the ways by basically counting them one by one. One billion ways is computed in ~ 8 seconds.

```
long compute(int N, int M, int[] positions, int[] dimensions) {
    if (M == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (positions[i] < dimensions[i]) {
            positions[i]++;
            sum += compute(N, M - 1, positions, dimensions);
            positions[i]--;
        }
        if (positions[i] > 1) {
            positions[i]--;
            sum += compute(N, M - 1, positions, dimensions);
            positions[i]++;
        }
    }
    return sum % 1000000007;
}
```